# WCF server certificate validation on LAN

Tags: .net, wcf, service, x509certificate, tls1.2

My service and my client reside two different LAN networks.
Service owns it's own signed certificate that is used to establish TCP TLS connection.
Client doesn't trust this certificate directly, but trusts it's root certificate. Optimally client shouldn't have to install any additional certificates.

Server doesn't care about client identity, but client should.
How does client validate that it is connecting to the expected server?

```
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://10.64.62.1:23269/CalculatorService"
                binding="netTcpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_ICalculatorService"
                contract="CalculatorService.ICalculatorService"
                name="clientEndpointBehavior"
                behaviorConfiguration="clientEndpointBehavior"
                >        
        <identity>
          <dns value="" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
```

The only setting in `<identity>` that doesn't lock identity to a single certificate or require windows `ClientCredentialType` is `<dns>`.
But in this case I cannot figure out what the value of `<dns>` should be and how does this prevent fake certificates that are also signed by a chain starting with trusted root CA?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the Identity section is used for identifying the server when connecting the particular server. It should be in the following form.

```
   <endpoint address="net.tcp://10.157.13.69:21011/" binding="netTcpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IService" contract="ServiceReference1.IService"
        name="NetTcpBinding_IService">
        <identity>
          <userPrincipalName value="VABQIA969VM\Administrator" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
```

Please check the below official description.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/service-identity-and-authentication
For how to ensure the security of certificate communication, please refer to the following document.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/working-with-certificates

Comment: Hi Abraham, userPrincipalName requires Windows client credential type to Windows which isn't suitable as client and service are in different networks. Also I read through both links and it does not provide suggestion for this case